# Windows 10 roaming profile error

Tags: windows-7, windows-10

New Windows 10 client that has existing windows 7 roaming profile.

Windows 10 has created .V5 profile folder but fails to create username folder in users folder on local drive, giving the using temp profile error message.

Given domain user admin permissions on Win10 machine but still no joy, an ideas what to do next?

Comment: What is the Error-Message in the Event-Viewer?